# Can Google Colab use local resources?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I am trying out Google Colab and wanted to know if I am able to use my local CPU, RAM, SSDs, and GPUs? I have tried to search a directory on my SSD but comes up empty. I found I have to upload my directories to my Google Drive and run the code:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Now that I have my directory established and I run my UNet I get the warning `` WARNING:tensorflow:There are non-GPU devices in `tf.distribute.Strategy`, not using nccl allreduce. `` and `INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0',)`
 I am using Linux RedHat 8 and have install the Nvidia NCCL drivers. I do not get this warning when using Jupyter Notebook.

Before my first epoch begins my session crashes and gives the message `Your session crashed after using all available RAM. Get more RAM`. In the upper right hand corner Colab says RAM: 12.72 GB and Disk: 107.77. 
My system has a Terabyte SSD for storage and 128 GB of RAM. Is there a way to run Colab with my resources or do I have to use theirs?

Comment: There's a bandwidth issue with using yours

Comment: I also want to use my local resources via colab. But I also want simultaneously to access data that is on my google drive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your own local resource by choosing "Local Runtime"

See documentation here:

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html